# How to download and extract .tar.gz file in windows 8 store apps

Tags: c#, windows-8

I have .tar.gz (.tgz) file from server. How to download and extract this file in windows 8 store apps and then need to store this extracted files in storage.

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late for the reply but adding my Answer so that it can be helpful to other users looking for some good zip/tar extractor.

One can use [Sharpcompress](https://sharpcompress.codeplex.com/) to extract, zip/tar package.

NoxHarmonium is true you need to download in local storage and then extract using above library.

Answer (score -1):

You can download the file with the [WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile.aspx) and put it into [local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144479/how-do-you-access-a-metro-apps-local-storage-in-a-desktop-application-in-window)
You can extract tar/gzip encoded files with the [.NET Zip Library](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/).

Comment: WebClient method not supported in metro app. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/0289a73e-7b5d-4127-949f-d48ab79543aa/

Comment: It has changed names, but it's almost the same thing and methods. Now it's called HttpClient

Comment: When i'm downloading .tar.gz file using HttpClient i received this error (An exception of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: A task was canceled.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.)                                   Below the my code:                                                  string resourceAddress ="My download link";
var cli = new HttpClient();
var respon = await cli.GetAsync(resourceAddress);
var res = await respon.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

Comment: The .NET Zip library referenced by NoxHarmonium (SharpZipLib) doesn't currently support WinRT.  Unfortunately a simple port of SharpZipLib doesn't seem possible since Microsoft's pursuit of creative destruction neglected to include "CryptoStream" and "ICryptoTransform" in WinRT.